# how to extract users out of outlook.msg group

Tags: outlook, text-extraction

so we use Microsoft outlook as our email client in my organization. A user forwarded me an outlook group of users she emails to. The file is of the format userlist.msg and I can open it in outlook and see the user names and email address. (I can't copy and paste from outlook) However, I can't seem to extract the list into a comma delimited file that I need to import into another system.

The best I could come up with was to print the list to a PDF file and then extract the members from the PDF, but many are line-wrapped and the user name and email address are not separated?

Any ideas on how to extract them?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it a bit more and found I could open the contract group in outlook and then go to **File --> Save As**. Then I could choose *Text only format (.txt)*. This gave me a neat enough file that I could work with.